# import org.apache.http HttpPost().getParams().setParameter(...) not working, nor is HttpPost().setEntity(list)

Tags: java, apache

I not getting either of the following to work:

```
import import org.apache.http....

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(new URI(url));

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    HttpParams postP = post.getParams();
    for ( String param : postParams.keySet() ) {
        String value = postParams.get( param );
        postP.setParameter( param, value );    // one way to set POST vals
        // params.add( new BasicNameValuePair( param, value) );  // alt way to set post vals?
    }
    // post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));  // alt way to set post vals?

    // transfer Access token to HTTP header
    if ( access_token != null ) {
        post.setHeader( "access_token", access_token );
    }

    HttpResponse response = sslClient.execute( post );
```

for either the setParameter() or setEntity() methods, the web server logs nothing.  for example Google+ (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token) replies that required params are not set.

However the following works but IMHO is pure messy; i'd prefer one of the above:

```
    URL uri = new URL(url);
    URLConnection conn = uri.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for ( String param : postParams.keySet() ) {
        String value = postParams.get( param );
        sb.append(param +"="+ value +"&");
    }
    //write parameters
    writer.write( sb.toString() );
    writer.flush();
```

any way to get the pure org.apache.http to work?

Comment: You just have to look at a working example on the apache project you're using and import the exact classes you need. If you don't know which classes are, import the whole package, then start importing the necessary classes.

Comment: the example POST seems to imply that one still must manually encode any attr/val pair into a string:
<br>HttpEntity[] requestBodies = {
                    new StringEntity(
                            "This is the first test request", ContentType.create("text/plain", Consts.UTF_8))<br> 
as with most examples, it's too trivial and lacking, therefore this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fluent API relieves the user from having to deal with manual deallocation of system
resources at the cost of having to buffer response content in memory in some cases.

```
Request.Get("http://targethost/homepage")
    .execute().returnContent();
Request.Post("http://targethost/login")
    .bodyForm(Form.form().add("username",  "vip").add("password",  "secret").build())
    .execute().returnContent();
```

Link to javadoc: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/fluent-hc/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/fluent/Request.html